Uploading a file with leptos
I am struggling quite a bit with understanding how to upload a multipart file in leptos.
Here is where I am at right now
let on_file_input = move |ev| {
    log!("file input");

    spawn_local(async move {
        let _ = upload(event_target_value(&ev)).await;
    });
};

view! {

    <input type="file"
        on:input=on_file_input
    />

and with the server function
#[server(Upload, "/api", "Cbor")]
pub async fn upload(file: String) -> Result<(), ServerFnError> {
    info!("got a file: {file}");

    Ok(())
}

it does "work" and I get the fakepath file location, but not the contents of the file.
I can't really find any examples of how to do this in the leptos book, but I assume it is possible somehow?
